# Call method from another class in a UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, action, custom-cell

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` with a class linked to it called `customCell.m`. (I didn't use xib.) In the cell there is a button. Is there a way to create the buttons action on the `mainVC.m` file, as apposed to `customCell.m`?

**Update**

Here is the code I tried implementing. What I did is, I called a method from `mainVC.m`.

`CustomCell.m`

```
- (IBAction)myButton:(id)sender
{
    CategorieViewController *mainVC = [[CategorieViewController alloc] init];
    [mainVC myMethod];
}
```

`MainVC.m`

```
- (void)myMethod:(id)sender
{
    UITableViewCell *clickedCell = (UITableViewCell *)[[[sender superview] superview] superview];
    NSIndexPath *clickedButtonPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForCell:clickedCell];

    NSLog(@"%@", clickedButtonPath);
}
```

> CategorieViewController myMethod]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd2dbd52a00
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CategorieViewController myMethod]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd2dbd52a00'

Comment: Can you show some code? you can create protocol or add target of your button to self in which you are using your customcell

Comment: You need to call `[mainVC myMethod:nil];` .Sorry i didn't see your error

Comment: @ChintaN-Maddy-Ramani Actually as I wrote in my answer, the OP has to change the line to `[mainVC myMethod:sender];` since the sender parameter is in fact used within `myMethod:` and therefore cannot be nil.

Comment: @LyndseyScott Questioner wrote question regarding how to call method. so i didn't saw error. (: . and ya and sender cannot be nil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `myMethod`, but the method is actually `myMethod:` and takes the sender as a parameter. Try changing:

```
[mainVC myMethod];
```

to:

```
[mainVC myMethod:sender];
```

Also, any sender you currently pass to `myMethod:` as a parameter, won't belong to `mainVC`'s tableview yet because you're creating a brand new `CategorieViewController` instance to perform the method call and its table has never been loaded.

Assuming `MainVC` is the visible view controller, you can change:

```
CategorieViewController *mainVC = [[CategorieViewController alloc] init];
```

to:

```
UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;
CategorieViewController *mainVC = (CategorieViewController*)nav.visibleViewController;
```

to get the current the current `MainVC` instance with the loaded tableview.

Comment: Your'e right. But now the `nslog` gives me a null. It doesn't give me the clicked buttons superView indexPath?

Comment: @MikeRally Is the button within a tableview cell? If so, it's still not going to be contained in your MainVC's `self.myTableView`, thus the nil value.

Comment: Yes, the buttons is in the `tableViewCell`. Why won't it work?

Comment: @MikeRally Hm, I see... So the button's within a custom cell within the MainVC?

Comment: Ya. What I'm trying to get is the selected buttons superview indexPath.

Comment: @MikeRally OK, well within the custom class, the button doesn't technically belong to mainVC's tableview yet because you're creating a brand new CategorieViewController to perform the method call and it's table has never been loaded... We can try getting your current view controller instance and see if it makes a difference...

Comment: oh I see. So what can I do to fix it?

Comment: @MikeRally Are you using a UINavigationController?

Comment: @MikeRally Assuming MainVC is the visible view controller, you can try changing `CategorieViewController *mainVC = [[CategorieViewController alloc] init];` to `CategorieViewController *view = (CategorieViewController*)self.navigationController.visibleViewController;` to get the current instance.

Comment: I can't do `self.navigationController..`. cuz `customCell.m` doesn't have a navigation controller. though mainVC.m has one

Comment: @MikeRally Oh yeah... Hm. Try using two lines of code then (the first is to get the nav controller): `UINavigationController *nav = (UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController;` 
    `CategorieViewController *mainVC = ( CategoriViewController*)nav.visibleViewController;`

Comment: @MikeRally OK, great. I'll update my answer to include that last bit then. :)